# What are callback classes in ActiveRecord::Base in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can some one explain 16 Callback classes in this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: They're already described pretty well in that guide.  Do you have a specific question or something that you're trying to get working?

Comment: I couldn't understand why after_destroy PictureFileCallbacks.new will call the instance method after_destroy in PictureFileCallbacks class

Comment: Well, it's also explained : "Note that we needed to instantiate a new PictureFileCallbacks object, since we declared our callback as an instance method. This is particularly useful if the callbacks make use of the state of the instantiated object. Often, however, it will make more sense to declare the callbacks as class methods:"

Comment: Why the model object expected by after_destroy is not PictureFile.new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think i understand your problem :

The after_destroy method in PictureFileCallbacks will be auto-magically called by rails :

When rails destroys your PictureFile object, it will instantiate a PictureFileCallbacks object and try to run an after_destroy method in it.

Everything works by convention, if you follow the naming properly everything will work out of the box.

Try it on a dummy project, and if you have some trouble making this work come back with some code to show.

Answer (score 0):

everything works by convention, you can try the following example:

```
#generate PictrueFile model with name attribute and generate seed
rails g model PictureFile name:string
#seeds.rb
3.times do |i|
  PictureFile.create(name: "name#{i}")
end

#create picture_file.rb and picture_file_callbacks.rb in model directory
#picture_file_callbacks.rb
class PictureFileCallbacks
  def after_destroy(picture_file)
    PictureFile.create(name: "demo")
  end
end

#picture_file_callbacks.rb
class PictureFile < ApplicationRecord
  after_destroy PictureFileCallbacks.new
end

execute the command in rails c
PictureFile.first.destroy 
PictrueFile.pluck(:name) #=>["name1", "name2", "demo"]
```